# Get authorize.net CIM hosted form token as a response

Tags: authorize.net, authorize.net-cim

I'm using CIM hosted page in my web-site page like,

```
<form method="post" action="https://secure.authorize.net/profile/manage"
id="formAuthorizeNetPage" style="display:none;">
<input type="hidden" name="Token"
value="pfGaUNntoTxZYeqqYDjGCQ4qyCHcsXGXLJ2i7MPCEiH6CH5n5qKqcl8EBiTClxu01B
SeH5eZg7LVUVVzw5kJKVMitQ3pyMB5UZCduMWd6Ku9aT2gyFm69EKMGfyWPmI4p+Bb4TJf2F0
7rInSrn2MWlM6f2xd7aRu1XBn0WXoPxK1j9FMGX2CNCoCBp3cOXB7"
/>
</form>
```

My confusion is how to get Token value here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pass this XML as a request,

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
        <getHostedProfilePageRequest xmlns=\"AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd\">"<merchantAuthentication>".
        <name>loginname</name>
        <transactionKey>transactionkey </transactionKey>
        </merchantAuthentication>
        <customerProfileId>cim_id</customerProfileId>
 <hostedProfileSettings>
 </hostedProfileSettings>
    </getHostedProfilePageRequest>
```

and check its response, where you can find token value for particular CIM user profile :)